# VSCode Python Intellisense stopped functioning properly? All variables show up as fields now

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I honestly dont remember when this started to happen but I haven't been able to fix it. No matter what variable I create the Intellisense only recognizes it as a field and doesn't give me any intellisense options. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETmRZ.png)

Comment: What version of VSCode are you running? Which particular Python plugin are you using to do the syntax highlighting?

Comment: This post isn't detailed very much and I have made a new post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305544/vscode-intellisense-stopped-working-properly-for-python. I completely wiped my VSCode and it seemed like everything returned back to normal until I restarted my VSCode. Only one extension which is the Python extension.

Answer (score 3):

The IntelliSense was provided by the language server. It looks like the language server which you are using has run across some problems.

You can try to switch to a different language server, such as 'pylance'. Change this setting in your settings.json file:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

If you want to take advantage of 'Pylance', you should download it in the marketPlace first, while 'Jedi' and 'Microsoft' needn't.

And maybe you will run across some problems in the future, you can try to reinstall the related extensions. And if you want to uninstall the VSCode clearly you shouldn't forget the extension folder which under like this:

```
C:\Users\xxx\.vscode\extensions
```

Comment: This actually was the issue for me. The language server was set to none for me and changing it to Pylance gave me intellisense.