# VSCode Intellisense stopped working properly for python

Tags: python, intellisense

I noticed any variables I make in python will no longer have proper IntelliSense suggestions. It seems that my VSCode is treating every variable I make as the same type?

[Here is how it is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOoMg.png)  [image]

[Here is how it looks when I'm typing in the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIlqx.png) [image]

[Here is how it looks on my Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEAiF.png) [image]

According to the Intellisense page on VSCodes websites the blue box symbol that appears when I'm calling the variable means its a field while the other symbol on my mac means its a Values and Enumerations. How can I make my desktop the same as my mac.

Also when I am typing an existing variable out and I add a "." to use a function on the variable and hit enter it will just copy the variable name again.I only get suggestions for intellisense if I have 2 ".". So stringG..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you changed some setting accidently, the fastest solution here is uninstall/install again!

Comment: I have done this multiple times. It seems after I completely uninstall which includes deleting all the VSCode files off my computer the issue fixes itself until I restart the program again.

Comment: Alright then, try this:

Open Run (Win + R)

Enter %appdata%

Press Enter

Delete the folder Code.

Voila! Restart Visual Studio Code and it is reset!

Here is a bat script to do the same 
    explorer.exe %appdata%
    del Code

Comment: I have done that and the problem still exists